# Why is my for loop skipping the last iteration in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

The third iteration of my for loop is only running once when it should be running twice.

First I have this array of words

```
String [] words = {"Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetur","adipiscing","elit.",,,,} 
spaceCount = 7;
wordCount = 4;
```

```
 while(wordCount>-1){
  output+=words[start];
  System.out.println("output:"+output);
  System.out.println("spaceCount:"+spaceCount);
  System.out.println("wordCount:"+wordCount);
  start++;
  System.out.println("j<:"+Math.ceil((double)spaceCount/(double)wordCount));
     for(j=0;j<Math.ceil((double)spaceCount/(double)wordCount);j++){
       System.out.println("j:"+j);
       output+=" ";
       spaceCount--;
     }
  wordCount--;
 }
```

I tried to typecast the Math ceil from double to int but it still produce the same result.

The result that appear is:

```
output:Lorem
spaceCount:7
wordCount:4
j<:2.0
j:0
j:1
output:Lorem  ipsum
spaceCount:5
wordCount:3
j<:2.0
j:0
j:1
output:Lorem  ipsum  dolor
spaceCount:3
wordCount:2
**j<:2.0
j:0**
output:Lorem  ipsum  dolor sit
**spaceCount:2
wordCount:1**
j<:2.0
j:0
output:Lorem  ipsum  dolor sit amet,
```

but it should be:

```
output:Lorem  ipsum  dolor
spaceCount:3
wordCount:2
j<:2.0
j:0
j:1
output:Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit
**spaceCount:1
wordCount:1
j<:1.0**
j:0
output:Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit amet,
```

Comment: The expected output you posted jumps from `spaceCount:3` to `spaceCount:1`. Your code only decrements `spaceCount` by 1 at a time.

Comment: I think its because of your condition in your for loop. it is not a constant variable because your spaceCount is decremented, and on each iteration, you evaluate the condition which evaluates the expression again. And when spaceCount = 1 and wordcount = 1 after you decrement space count? j is equal to 1. your condition is j <1, meaning it terminates